# How to search within an array?

Tags: javascript, dom, search

I have this function that it suppose to get all the a tags from the page, I'm trying to all all the anchors within those links, but I keep getting Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method errors, 
I've tried using split, search and indexOf, but everything gives mes the same error, what am I doing wrong?

I know I'm getting all the a tags, the first alert returns their total number.
Here's what I have:

```
// get all the link tags from the page
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

//alert(a.length)


for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
{
    // check which links have an anchor within them
    if(a[i].search("#") > 1)
    {
        alert("yes");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("no");
    }
}
```

Comment: `a[i]` is a DOM Element (like the error says). If you want to access the `href` value of that element, then do `a[i].href` or `a[i].getAttribute('href')`.

Comment: I'd go with a[i].getAttribute('href');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it without looping using selectors.

```
var aWithAnchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="#"]');
```

Then you can get all the links:

```
console.log([].map.call(aWithAnchors, function (link) {
    return link.href;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor elements have an `href` property you can use:

```
if (a[i].href.search("#") != -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the href attribute, like so:

```
if(a[i].href.search("#") > -1)
```

N.B. Indexes start at 0, so you will need to check if the result of `search()` is greater than -1